# Как достать из массива индекс удаленного объекта?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив arr с определенным количеством чисел. По нажатию из него удаляются некоторые объекты (в случайном порядке). Когда элемент удаляется, то в консоли по его индексу выдается undefined, поэтому я решил определять удаленный элемент по нему. Нужно достать из него индексы всех удаленных элементов и записать их в массив arr1 , но в моем случае выдает не индекс, а [object Object]. Как быть?

И да, удалять элементы методом 'delete' было необходимостью, поэтому сменить метод на splice не вариант.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let arr1 = [];
let index;

delete arr[3, 6, 9];
arr.forEach((item, index, array) => {

    if ({ item } = 'undefined') {
        index = { index };
        item.unshift(index);
        alert(index);            //возвращает [object Object]
    };
});
```

Comment: `if (item === 'undefined') { arr1.unshift(index); alert(index); }`

Comment: `delete arr[3, 6, 9];` Удаляет по последнему индексу в массиве т.е. 1 элемент. `index = { index };` переменной присваивается объект  с ключом `index` и значением текущего индекса. `{index : 9}` Зачем в фигурные скобки брать `if ({ item } = 'undefined')` ?

Comment: @Rudi, Это деструктуризация и в item запишется `undefined`, потому что у строки нет свойства `item`